# Firebase pods installation error other pods installation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, firebase

I am really stuck at this step of Firebase Installation to my iOS app. I installed some other pods but it worked perfectly. But after Firebase installation it makes an error **'Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)'**. I figure out this problem. This is because of **pod 'GVRSDK'**. When I delete this **pod 'GVRSDK'** then it works perfectly. The error mention in the given image.

[image]

My app pod content is given below:

```
pod ‘Firebase/Messaging’
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
pod 'Google/SignIn'
pod 'GVRSDK', '0.8.5'
pod 'RSKImageCropper'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using the deprecated  'Google/SignIn' may lead to problems, change it to 'GoogleSignIn'. If you still running into issues, share your Podfile.lock

Answer (score 1):

In you Pod file you should use proper comma according to your Pod, Firebase pod section should be like'Firebase/Messaging' use that instead of 'Google/CloudMessaging' because that pod is deprecated. Delete that line in your pod and re-install it. That will fix your problem.

Comment: I did this but doesn't work for me. Did you create a test project for this?

Comment: Ok I imported your pod file to test project and i found the solution. pod 'Google/CloudMessaging' is deprecated so you are using 'Firebase/Messaging' instead of that. So remove the 'Google/CloudMessaging' and re-install your pod your error will be gone. I hope that is helped for you